# Why is the HTML button background color filled in wrong?

Tags: html, css

New to HTML. The toggle button changes between the patient and employee login. The background colour for patient login (image 1) works, but the employee login (image 2) does not. I have tried changing the width in #btn but it's never filled in correctly. How do I fix this?

The code:

```css
.button-box {
  width: 58%;
  margin: 40px auto;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgb(225, 224, 224);
}

.toggle-btn {
  padding: 10px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  outline: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: small;
}

#btn {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 0.1s;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #1f9cd5, #c7e3f1);
}
```

```html
<div class="button-box">
  <div id="btn"></div>
  <button type="button" class="toggle-btn">Patient Login</button>
  <button type="button" class="toggle-btn"> Employee Login</button>
</div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzBu7.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mT7vP.png

Comment: Why don't you apply the background color to the buttons directly?

Comment: Probably your div is not postioned in a way that matches the actual button position. If you apply the background-color (e.g. via css class) to the button directly, your issue should be resolved.

Comment: not sure what is causing that btn div to shift around but instead of that, why not just have a selected class that you put on the different buttons depending on which is selected, then you can add your gradient to that instead - seems a lot easier than having a floating background

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like this:

```css
.button-box {
  width: 58%;
  margin: 40px auto;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgb(225, 224, 224);
}

.toggle-btn {
  padding: 10px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  outline: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: small;
}

#btn {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 0.1s;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #1f9cd5, #c7e3f1);
}
```

```html
<div class="button-box">
  <div style="position: relative;width: max-content;">
    <div id="btn"></div>
    <button type="button" class="toggle-btn">Patient Login</button>
    <button type="button" class="toggle-btn"> Employee Login</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Explanation:
The additional `div` resizes on the size of the 2 buttons, so the `div#btn` takes the maximum size.

If you don't need to add anything inside the `div#btn` it would be better to put the `linear-gradient` directly to the parent `div`.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.button-box {
  width: 58%;
  margin: 40px auto;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgb(225, 224, 224);
}

.toggle-btn {
  padding: 10px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  outline: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: small;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #1f9cd5, #c7e3f1);
}

#btn {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 0.1s;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="button-box">
  <div id="btn"></div>
  <button type="button" class="toggle-btn">Patient Login</button>
  <button type="button" class="toggle-btn"> Employee Login</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).